# Java MailBox reader

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

I am trying to read the emails from microsoft exchange server, so I requested the details from admin, he was not exactly sure but gave me these details,

```
ab-mbx01 = server
ag 07 = storage group
ab-mbx01 DB01 S1000 = Database/DatabaseName
ab-mbx01.de.domain.com = mailbox server.
```

So I used mailbox server as host and tried to connect using the EWS java api, but I have recieved error saying connected refused.

Could any one let me know, should I use insert the other details in the code and how to insert them in the code?

Thank you.

Code:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    service.setUrl(new java.net.URI("https://" + "mailbox server"
            + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
    service.setTraceEnabled(true);

    //IF connected view items
    ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
    view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
    view.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject,
            ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived));


    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
    LogicalOperator.Or, new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "EWS"), 
    new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "API")),view);

    System.out.println("Total number of items found: " + findResults.getTotalCount());

    for (Item item : findResults)
            {
                    System.out.println(item.getSubject());
                    System.out.println(item.getBody());
                    // Do something with the item.
            }
```

Using JavaMail Api I used the same code as

```
http://www.javaplex.com/blog/using-javamail-api-read-emails-from-gmail/
```

Comment: I think you will need credentials

Comment: I am using my username and password as my credentials!

Comment: You can try JavaMail(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Comment: same error even if i am using the javamail (connection refused).

Comment: Can you share your code that you have tried ?

Comment: share some more code man

Comment: for using javamail I used the same code from this website http://www.javaplex.com/blog/using-javamail-api-read-emails-from-gmail/